# Is it correct to calculate Correlation coefficient

Tags: statistics

Let X and Y respectively denote lists of internal and external marks obtained by a group of students. Internal includes test,quiz and assignment components. Where as external includes only test component. Is it correct to calculate correlation coefficient between X and Y? That is whether X and Y are linearly related or not?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the correlation coefficient is a measure of the linear dependency between two variables.

The fact that $X$ and $Y$ share a component isn't harmful: assuming that $Y$ is a linear combination of a variable $Z$ independent of $X$, and $X$ in some proportion, $Y=Z+\lambda X$.

Then the linear model $Y=aX+b$ can be written as $Z=(a-\lambda)X+b$, another linear model. The correlation coefficient is not influenced, as it expresses the unexplained variance.

Comment: Yes, X and Y can be linearly dependent. Thanks for your nice explanation. But, whether correlation coefficient of X and Y will give any meaningful connection?

Comment: @user190399: why not ?

Comment: If correlation coefficient is.69 , what can be the connections between internal(X) and external(Y)

Comment: The linear model explains 69% of the variance.

Answer (score 1):

As aforementioned, this is one of the assumptions of the **PMCC**:

```
     There needs to be a linear relationship between the two variables.
```

I'd say that one of the easier ways to test this out would be to construct a scatter plot from your given data *(you can use a program such as Excel)*. You can then visually inspect the plot to see if your data satisfies the above assumption.

Here are some examples of scatter plots:

[image]